# How long does AV video URL stay in memory?

Tags: swift, url, video, memory

I am making an application that allows users to post videos & images.

---

But sometimes when internet connection is not available, and the post fails to be uploaded, then it remains locally with a big button "try again".

Until the user clicks it, I store the post values

```
class DependingPost: NSObject {
    var index : Int!
    var message: String!
    var leftTime: Int!

    var posting : Bool = false

    var pickedFiles : [Any]!

    init(index : Int, message: String, leftTime: Int, pickedFiles: [Any]){
        self.index = index
        self.message = message
        self.leftTime = leftTime
        self.pickedFiles = pickedFiles

        super.init()
    }

}
```

As you see, there's a `pickedFiles : [Any]!` part.

It may contain `UIImage` and `URL` (for video)

---

My question is, how long does the video live in the memory? Is it possible that user closes then opens the app, and the video will be gone?

- If the depending post gets deleted, how can I release the video from the memory (URL)?

Comment: _Swift Tip:_Don't use force unwrapped var properties… `var index : Int!`, use `let index: Int` instead. This looks like it could be a `struct` rather than a `class`.

Answer (score 2):

This depnds on how you preserve it , if you cache it in a temporary array whether it's instance/global , then everything will be cleared when you close the app , instead you need to store the video may be in Documents or Library/Application Support to make it live until you delete the app or clear it yourself , if the video is deleted you need to remove the associated object both from the array and from the cache , so you need to store it with an id